# Parallax RFID + PI only reads first time

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-3, rfid

I used the following code from this [post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8431/pi-parallax-rfid-reader-python-only-reading-one-tag/8835#8835?newreg=c48d8a49e95b4768b8c97ea67145132a)

```
import serial
import time

serial = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=2400)
while True:
    if serial.inWaiting() > 0:
        read_result = serial.read(12)
        print("Read card {0}" . format(read_result.decode(encoding='utf-8')))
        print("Sleeping 2 seconds")
        time.sleep(2)
        serial.flushInput() # ignore errors, no data
```

but still get the same problem as the original poster where the initial tag scan reads and any subsequent tries are unsuccessful

output is as follows with error:

```
Read card 04193DCBD7
Sleeping in 2 seconds
Read card                      # notice second read empty
Sleeping in 2 seconds
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Test/TestRFID2.py", line 8, in <module>
   print("Read card {0}" . format(read_result.decode(encoding='utf-8')))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3: invalid start byte
```

Errors fall in different positions (i.e. 1, 2, or 3)

Have tried different scripts as well with same outcome.  I have also disabled the serial console [as described here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/47383/5538).

[image: My schematic with all connections]

Comment: Is this a Pi 3 by any chance?

Comment: Yes it is, can you help?

Comment: Yep -- although physically the UART serial pins are in the same place as on every other model of Pi, on the 3 `/dev/ttyAMA0` *doesn't refer to them*.  See the answers on the duplicate question.  Everything else should be the same.

Comment: @goldilocks I've changed the port to `/dev/ttyS0` but now the UnicodeDecodeError appears immediately, how do I check the `/boot/cmdline.txt` file to make sure the console output is properly disabled for that node. Sorry but I am new to python and raspberry pi

Comment: If you aren't using the serial console (most people don't, IMO this is a strange choice made by Raspbian and/or the Pi Foundation), the easiest way to disable it is probably via `raspi-config`. The two components are the reference in `cmdline.txt` (the only mention of a console there should be `console=tty1`, make sure afterward) and the spawning of a terminal line by the init system, which on jessie `systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyS0.service` should get rid of...

Comment: ...But try `raspi-config` first, it will probably work. I am not sure exactly where the option is but I think on the front menu.  There is no so much stuff there to look through anyway ;)

Comment: Whoops, sorry Carl -- that should probably have been `systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyS0.service` (edited above).  I've also edited my answer in the duplicate question to include these details.  The `raspi-config` option is *Advanced Options -> Enable/Disable shell and kernel messages on the serial connection*.

Comment: So I've disabled the serial console, as well as rebooting the device...Once booted up I check `/boot/cmdline.txt` and notice that the only console shown is `console=tty1` but when I try to run my code I get `[errno2] could not open port /dev/ttyS0: [Errno2] No such file or directory: /dev/ttyS0`

Comment: Okay.  I've reopened this and edited in a line to make it clear you have the serial console disabled so you do not have to go through this again -- but do double check that ;)  You might also want to include a photo of the physical connections; although it seems very straighforward it is not unusual for people to have let a small mistake there go unnoticed (such as not crossing the RX and TX lines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides changing changing the port from `/dev/ttyAMA0` to `/dev/ttyS0` 
because the default device node for the Pi 3 is different.

I figured out what my problem was and it lies within the `config.txt` file, I added the line `enable_uart=1`, this will enable the device itself.
Tested it and it works 100% for me.